# Create an edge between a "real" and an array modifier vertex?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices

I want to hit "F" and add an edge between the last vertex of the real object, and the first vertex of it's array-modifier-duplicated clone.

The problem is, selecting the first vertex of the clone actually selects the first vertex of the original instead, so the edge goes in the wrong place.

[image]
[image]

This is wrong: the new edge should connect the gear teeth together, not close off the tooth.

[image]

There doesn't seem to be a way to set the cursor to the cloned vertex either.

What's the fastest way to add an edge (and required vertex) as if the cloned vertex were actually there?

Answer (score 1):

### Scenario 1

Make one copy of Array real to be able snap extruded vertex and add Array modifier again. Like:

- Duplicate Array modifier (and disable one of them)
- Set Count 2 and Apply
- Enable Snap > Vertex type
- Create connection by Extruding <kbd>E</kbd> Vertex
- Delete unwanted parts (second teeth)
- Enable Array modifier back

### Scenario 2

Do it out of edit mode by another object and than join them. Like ...

- in Edit mode <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> first vertex
- Separate > Selected <kbd>P</kbd>
- in Object mode select separeted vertex, go to edit mode
- enable *Snap* tool and to *Vertex*
- select vertex, Extrude <kbd>E</kbd>, Snap to first Array copy
- go to Object mode and Join these two Objects <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

BTW Do you know there is a [addon GearGenMaster](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtBO3YIkWTs)?